# How to use org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request in a webapp?

Tags: maven, jetty, classpath, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-9

In my ServletFilter, I want to use specific jetty API exposed in the HttpServletRequest implementation.

I launched it like that:

```
final Request jettyRequest = Request.getBaseRequest(request)
```

If I want to avoid ClassNotFoundException, I must add the jetty-server artifact to my maven dependencies. But if I do that, getBaseRequest returns null because 'request instanceof Request' returns false instead of true.

This is certainly due to conflict between jetty and application classloaders because both of them have loaded 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request' class. I tried several configurations, but I was not able to make the Request class exposed to my webapp without adding the dependency in WEB-INF/lib, which causes the classpath issue.

My application is launched with "mvn jetty:run-forked" and configured like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}</webAppSourceDirectory>
            <systemProperties>
                <force>true</force>
            </systemProperties>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
            <webAppConfig>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
            </webAppConfig>
            <jettyXml>../jetty.xml,../jetty-ssl.xml,../jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
            <jvmArgs>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Xbootclasspath/p:${settings.localRepository}/org/mortbay/jetty/alpn/alpn-boot/${alpn-version}/alpn-boot-${alpn-version}.jar</jvmArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need access to the Jetty internal `Request` object? (this object is subject to change with each release of Jetty)

Comment: I'm working on experimental server-push support in a web application that needs server-specific API. On Jetty, I want to access the PushBuilder API from Jetty Request class.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding a WebAppContext configuration file that contains:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">true</Set>
</Configure>
```

The file must be referenced in jetty-maven-plugin like that:

```
<contextXml>../jetty-context.xml</contextXml>
```